# Setting wireless to default in ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: networking, wireless, wicd

I am using ubuntu server 12.04 to control a robot. There are laser scanners connected to eth0 and eth1, and I am using wicd-curses to control the wireless. I am sshing into the robot computer from a workstation computer, and sending the robot commands from there. When I have the laser scanners plugged in I can't ssh into the robot computer because it defaults to eth0's ip address. How can I set it up so that ubuntu uses the wireless ip as the primary?

Thanks

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/452746/make-wifi-preferable-over-wired-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04